# Short​ story with a human being "dead" for several seconds during faster-than-light space travel

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a short story I read a long time ago, so I don't have the slightest idea who is the author.

In it, scientists built a machine that can solve problems by feeding it, as far as I remember, specially coded data (or maybe not, but some cards were used).

The machine was programmed to keep the humans from harm, and scientists wanted to solve the problem of traveling to distant places in space, which requires really high speed or some such thing, that makes it impossible for the machine to process this question (because it would harm humans).

Scientists find some trick and the device is able to give an answer, but when an actual human is using the suggested technology, he appears in some kind of, I don't know, hell, though he was alive again after the end of the travel.

Comment: It is part of the robot series by Issac Asimov but I don't remember the title.

Comment: Thank you very-very much! I found it. It's "Escape!".

Comment: Somehow this feels as a prelude to Event Horizon movie :D

Answer (score 9):

It is a short story called ["Escape"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44193) (1945) that is in the collection [*I, Robot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%2C_Robot) by Isaac Asimov.